# How to loop through an array of Strings and print the strings that has certain characters?

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

```
public static String[] data = { "Achelous", "Ares", "Clytemnestra", "Eurystheus", "Icarus", "Naiads", "Phlegethon", "Sterope",
        "Acheron", "Argo", "Cocytus", "Euterpe", "Io", "Napaeae", "Phosphor", "Stheno", "Achilles", "Argus",
        "Creon", "Favonius", "Iobates", "Narcissus", "Phrixos", "Styx", "Actaeon", "Ariadne", "Creьsa", "Furies",
        "Iphigenia", "Nemesis", "Pirithous", "Symplegades", "Admetus", "Arion", "Creusa", "Gaea", "Iris",
        "Neoptolemus", "Pleiades", "Syrinx", "Adonis", "Artemis", "Cronus", "Galatea", "Ismene", "Nereids", "Pluto",
        "Tantalus", "Aeacus", "Asclepius", "Cybele", "Ganymede", "Iulus", "Nestor", "Plutus", "Tartarus", "Aegeus",
        "Astarte", "Cyclopes", "Glaucus", "Ixion", "Nike", "Pollux", "Taygeta", "Aegisthus", "Astraea", "Daedalus",
        "Graces", "Jason", "Niobe", "Polymnia", "Telemachus", "Aegyptus", "Atalanta", "Danae", "Graeae", "Jocasta",
        "Nona", "Polynices", "Terpsichore", "Aeneas", "Athena", "Daphne", "Hades", "Lachesis", "Notus",
         };


public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("The length of the array is " + data.length);
     for(int i=0; i<data.length; i++){
       if(data[i].length()<=4){
          System.out.println(data);
         }
    }
    //for(String name : data){
    //  System.out.println(name);
    //}

}
```

How to actually loop through the loop of Strings, identify which words has for example 2 character and print it?

Comment: 1 loop and 1 conditional statement. in your case, change the <= 4 to == 2

Comment: @Stultuske Yeah i know, but i can't figure out how to write it so I can go through the characters to count them

Comment: @VenetsiaKrusteva There is no need to count characters, unless you want to e.g. ignore whitespaces. In Java, any `String` knows its own length.

Comment: @VenetsiaKrusteva why would you do that? just use the .length method as you did in your example

Comment: @Stultuske True, Thank you!

Comment: @VenetsiaKrusteva Anyway, a `String` is, inside, an array of characters. You can get a copy of it (you can't access it directly, String is immutable once created). You can also access the characters by `characterAt`, though be careful, it is Unicode-16 and there can be some unicode code points that are wider than 16 bits. In that case, `codePointAt` is more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`qualifyingLength` below is the length in question. `data` is the input array of `String`.

```
public static void printWhatQualifies(String[] data, int qualifyingLength) {
    for(String string: data) {
        if(qualifyingLength == string.length()) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approch is using streams...

```
Arrays.stream(data).filter(s -> s.length() == 2).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: OP doesn't seem to be acquainted with the idea of looping. Internal iteration is a far-fetched concept at this time.

Comment: @C.Weber Don't actually know this, but i will give it a try

Comment: Yea, I guess for a novice programmer this is better to skip (for now). You don't want to confuse her and make her quit, do you? :)

Comment: @Vlasec Won't quit :D I will just continue researching